# WebForms detailsview -- are both Edit and Insert templates needed?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, detailsview

This question would apply to a typical CRUD page allowing the user to ADD, and/or EDIT a specific record.

Question about WebForms DetailsView control (and possibly FormView and GridView) -- Do we really need to specify BOTH the Edit-template AND the Insert-template which are essentially the same?
If not, which template should be designed/specified?

Your answer and comments are welcome.
Thanks...J.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience you don't have to specify *either* template. In fact the only time I even use templates is if I want to customize certain attributes that you can only do via a template. I typically use templates when I want to have RequiredFieldValidators. Otherwise I don't use them at all. But you certainly can have neither, either or both.

That being said, I do usually have Item, Insert and Edit templates when I do need the extra flexibility of templates. Seems more complete to me.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I was thinking that I am duplicating art-work (visual design) and validation-controls in the Insert-template when it is already defined in the Edit-template.  I reference this question to a "typical" CRUD page where user must add or modify a record (no matter how complex or simple the record is). I was asking so that I could save art-work coding time.  Thanks.